# ASP.NET MVC Custom Routing in Sub Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have searched on Google (may be with wrong keyword) and visited the tutorials of ASP.NET/MVC website. But didn't understand the routing of MVC properly.
I have a scenario of the following figure. I want to display the Index.cshtml when the website lunched.
 [image]

I have changed the RegisterRoutes method of Global.asax.cs file in various ways. The latest code (not working) is below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "App", // Route name
            "App/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I will be very happy if someone explains the MapRoute method with different example along with answering my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 has a built in feature for sub folders. That is called **Areas** (thanks @Morten for let me know the word).
 But after finishing the [**MSDN Walkthrough**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461420.aspx) for Areas, I was still unable to run the web application. The error was showing **Configuration errors**. @Danny also noticed that. 
Then I searched and found that, the **Web.config files in the sub folders shouldn't contain application specific properties**.
So, I removed those properties from the Web.config files. Then I was able to run. But there were some runtime errors when I wanted to navigate to my sub folder/area views. The error was **"Could not load type ‘System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<..<>’"** when I click on the links for the views of the Areas folder.

Then I again searched and found helpful [**this**](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/04/05/could-not-load-type-systemwebmvcviewpage/) post. And then my application successfully run and I can navigate all of the pages.

Comment: My first edit asked if you were trying to create an Area before @Morten's comment ;) Glad you got everything working.

Comment: @Danny: Bro, I didn't know the keyword in that time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problem is with your routes, I believe it is caused by moving your View and Controller folders to the App folder.

MVC use "convention over configuration" for stuff like where the folders are located, I'm guessing it can't find the Views/Controllers in the new folders?

From [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1):

> These folders are included even in an
>   Empty ASP.NET MVC application because
>   the ASP.NET MVC framework by default
>   uses a “convention over configuration”
>   approach and makes some default
>   assumptions based on folder naming
>   conventions. For instance, controllers
>   look for views in the Views folder by
>   default without you having to
>   explicitly specify this in your code.
>   Sticking with the default conventions
>   reduces the amount of code you need to
>   write, and can also make it easier for
>   other developers to understand your
>   project.

I'm not saying that it's not possible to have a folder structure like you have, I just dont believe its supported out of the box.
Personally I'd recommend moving back to the default, if you need to keep this structure then I think you may need to implement your own ControllerFactory and ViewEngine (I'm not sure if these are the correct hooks that you would need to change).

Edit:
Are you trying to implement App as an Area?

Edit2:
If you are trying to add App as an area there are some steps you will need to follow, The reason I wasn't sure if this was what you were trying to do is because I thought areas had to exist within an Areas folder.
There are some steps outlines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461420.aspx) Including how to register your area if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: The structure fits exactly with using an area. Edit your post to show how to define and register an App area, and you'll get an upvote from me - unless someone beats you to it ;)

Comment: To use that kind of folder you'll have to add the appropiate controllers namespace to the defaultcontrollerfactory and create a custom ViewEngine (inherit from RazorViewEngine) to look in the correct folders. Maybe you're trying to create an Area, with will be easier if you want to use a route like /App/Home/

Comment: @Morten Mertner I thought that you had to have your areas defined within an Areas folder? Thats why I'm not sure what the intent is. Please correct me if I am incorrect about the Areas folder?

Comment: @DannyLane My mistake, you do indeed need an Areas folder.

Comment: @Morten: The keyword "Area" is new to me. I will finish your given msdn link and then get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @Morten: I just completed the walkthrough of msdn. but now i am having the "Configuration Error". In details: "Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS" any idea?

Comment: @Foysal I think this may be because you have a section defined in the web.config of a sub folder that shouldn't be there. You can have a web.config in the sub folder but not all settings are allowed there, some have to remain out in the main web.config (application level). Does the error indicate a section that might be the problem? HTH